# URL schemes in plist for using OAuth2

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm building an iOS app and trying to use the SoundCloud API. I registered my app and created a redirectURI: APP_NAME://soundcloud. Then, in Xcode, I added a URL scheme as APP_NAME and URL identifier as com.BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER and in my AppDelegate do the following:

```
[SCSoundCloud setClientID:@"CLIENT_ID"
                   secret:@"SECRET"
              redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"APP_NAME://soundcloud"]];
```

If I launch the app on the simulator and then type in APP_NAME://soundcloud into Safari's address bar, it successfully bounces me back into my app. However, within the app, I continuously get the following errors:

```
*** Assertion failure in +[SCRequest performMethod:onResource:usingParameters:withAccount:sendingProgressHandler:responseHandler:]

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Resource '(null)' is invalid because the scheme is not 'https'.'
```

Why is the resource '(null)' and the scheme 'https'? Where do I change this and how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

That method invokes the `SCRequest` `performMethod` method and requires an https link, which means deep linking into other apps is not supported.

```
NSAssert1([[aResource scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"], @"Resource '%@' is invalid because the scheme is not 'https'.", aResource);
```

To get around this, implement Universal Links in your app which will redirect the https link to your app if it is installed on the device.